# Get-AdComputer format and sort list

Tags: powershell

Attemping to get names of all computers, then sort them in ascending order, it gives me the list of computers, but wont sort them, what am I missing?

```
 Get-AdComputer -Filter * | format-table  Name; Sort-Object Name -Ascending  >> C:\Users\me\Desktop\All.txt
```

also tried

```
 Get-AdComputer -Filter * | {format-table  Name; Sort-Object Name -Ascending  >> C:\Users\me\Desktop\All.txt}
```

but returns error

Comment: See Mathias' answer below; however, there is no Ascending parameter on Sort-Object; it's the default. There's only a Descending parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Sort-Object` *before* formatting the output:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * |Sort-Object Name -Ascending |Format-Table Name
```

or grab just the `Name` values and sort those directly:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |Sort-Object -Ascending
```

Comment: See I had tried the double pipe but had format table first, awesome!

Comment: Yep, _always_ format last: "Filter first, format last," or "Filter left, format right."